# Bitwise shift in mysql

Tags: mysql, bitwise-operators

How can I make a bitwise shift in MySQL? Is there any specific instruction or operator? If not, how to simulate it optimally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the bitwise operators in `MySQL` first: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

Then you have left shift:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_left-shift

And right shift:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_right-shift

Answer (score 3):

To use a [bitwise shift in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html), you can use `<<` or `>>` for left shift or right shift respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is shift operators available, ie [>>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-functions.html#operator_right-shift) for right shift.