# Phalcon MySQL query with Bitwise (Shift-Left Operators)

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I have user model in where i need to select some other related models, however my query is not a standard one, so i dont think i can use find() or query:: to get the result, so i am thinking to use "modelmanager" and its phql to do the job, however i get empty set as result why is that

SQL Query is

```
 SELECT title FROM var_religion WHERE (15 & (1 << (id - 1))) ORDER BY id DESC
```

however when use following function insde user model it doesnt seems to be working any idea ? ```

```
 public function partner(){

//$p_religions = VarReligion::find(
//    array(
 //        "conditions" => " (:var: & (1 << (id - 1))) ",
 //        "bind"       => array("var"=> $this->religion),
 //        "order"     => "id DESC"
 //    )
 //);
 $phql = "SELECT title FROM var_religion WHERE (15 & (1 << (id - 1))) ORDER BY id DESC";
 $p_religions = $this->manager->executeQuery($phql);
 var_dump($p_religions);
}
```

i get no output why ?? how do i do this query ?

Note:
if this is not possible with the phalcon mysql models , i would rather need at least an php equelent to convert this logic into an

```
SELECT title FROM var_religion WHERE id IN (1,,,,,4);
```

Comment: Can you run your query right in mysql with a shell program or phpMyAdmin or similar? Does it succeed then?

Comment: of course query is perfectly valid and returns results ...

Comment: if you dont know what is leftshit operator read below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670611/bitwise-shift-in-mysql

Comment: always pays to check that the query is actually pulling results, even if php doesn't seem to get them. And I am aware of the left shi**f**t operator, thanks

Comment: thanks if this is not possible with the phalcon mysql models , i would rather need at least an php equelent to convert this login into an WHERE id IN (1,,,,,4);

Comment: Not sure if it's possible or not but to do `id IN (1,,,,,4)` just use BETWEEN. `WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 4`

Comment: as i highlighted the bitwise logic needs to be converted into a IN because its not always between when its converted, its represent check box values at the frontend...however since the db store it as 15 (this is binary format of the checkbox values)

Comment: Sounds like I'm way out of my depth here but one last question: can you convert/cast the column before running the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed an alike request with this attempt:

```
$religions = new \Application\Models\Religions();

$sql = 'SELECT id FROM religions WHERE
        (15 & (1 << (id - 1))) > 0  ORDER BY id DESC';

$result = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple(
    null,
    $religions,
    $religions->getReadConnection()->query($sql)
);

print_r($result->toArray());
```

Note that I have to do `> 0` cause of PgSQL type restrictions. Other attempt would be to shorten query itself to:

```
 SELECT id, (15 & (1 << (id - 1))) as rank FROM religions HAVING rank > 0
```

More in [Phalcon docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/phql.html#using-raw-sql).

### Phql, which you are using, does not support bitwise operators, so you need to hack it this way.

---

PS:
when using `SELECT *` in above query, you can benefit from model functions, eg:

```
$result = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple(null, $keyword, $keyword->getReadConnection()->query($sql));

foreach($result as $r) {
    var_dump($r->getId());
}
```